# Order of words in multiple-word variables (and identifiers in general)

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

This is a question about variable naming (or naming of identifiers in general).

Head-initial (right-branching) languages tend to have postnominal modifiers, while head-final (left-branching) languages tend to have prenominal modifiers. Modifiers include adjectives, adverbs, possessive pronouns, and demonstratives. Here is an example (English translation: "loud music"):

- Korean (left-branching): 시끄러운 음악
- French (right-branching): musique forte

As soon as we make our examples longer, we will see that in reality languages are very [inconsistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Branching_(linguistics)&oldid=1030689358#Tendencies) about this, English being a case in point. Also, in my personal experience, the shorter the word, the more likely that it occurs on the left anyway (for reasons of psycholinguistic parsing: you can discern the tree structure earlier that way). But, wouldn't it be beneficial to be consistent in this regard when naming long variables consisting of many words?

Here are some examples:

- `redblackTree_leftSubtree_color` (mixed; natural English) vs `treeRedblack_subtreeLeft_color` (consistently right-branching) – note how I didn't change "subtree" into "treesub" (treating it as an unchangeable lexicalized chunk)
- `old_bTree_order` (mixed; natural English) vs `bTree_old_order` (consistently right-branching) – in this case I didn't change "bTree" to "treeB"
- `myStrings_set_size` (mixed; natural English) vs `stringsMy_set_size` (consistently right-branching)
- `len_median_sortedListCopy` (mixed; natural English) vs `listSortedCopy_median_length` (consistently right-branching)
- `arrayIndexOutofboundsException` [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in Java] (mixed; natural English) vs `exceptionArrayIndexOutofbounds` (consistently right-branching)

I personally have a strong preference for very strictly right-branching naming. That way, we always proceed from higher/abstract/general concepts to lower/concrete/specialized ones, that is from large wholes to their small component parts. Needless to say, this goes against natural language usage in English.

Note incidentally that a case for strictly left-branching naming would be that often the type is guessable from the most specific element. For example, `order_old_bTree` is almost certainly an integer. Additionally, the leftmost element nicely aligns with the current indentation level.

**Are there any best practices or guidelines about the branching order of variables/identifiers consisting of many components?**

I skimmed the 108 answers of [Do people in non-English-speaking countries code in English?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1483/81063), but I couldn't find any of them addressing this aspect.

The only related thing that I could find in the respective Wikipedia article is the [OF Language's PRIME-MODIFIER-CLASS word scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Naming_convention_(programming)&oldid=1135926444#Composite_word_scheme_(OF_Language)) (I know nothing about this beyond what Wikipedia says).

There exist at least 2 related but programming language–specific questions on this site:

- Java: [Word order in class names in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25167231/2057969)
- Python: [Recommended word order of names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44937538/2057969) [closed]

Comment: What you call left branching is more natural if you use the English language since for instance *customerAccountNumber* reads better than *numberAccountCustomer*.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom English is mixed-branching, but you are right that for nominal structures left-branching is generally more natural. However when you write the occasional function where data structures are nested deeply, the inconsistencies come to light, and I wish everyone would just use a consistent naming scheme.

Comment: When you have a designator for a structured variable, e.g `customers[i].accountNumber`,  you read the selectors from left to right. I don't see anything inconsistent about that.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom English is inconsistent in its branching, but what you mention points to another inconsistency: that array access and member access is right-branching in seemingly most programming languages, while English is left-branching for nominal structures. When you assign the result to a variable, what do you name it? In some contexts, `acctNo` will do, but what if access is computationally expensive or your algorithm operates on several such variables? `acctNoCustomerA`/`acctNoCustomerB` or `customerAAcctNo`/`customerBAcctNo` or (heaven forbid) `noAcctACustomer`/`noAcctBCustomer`?

Comment: A designator like `customers[i].accountNumber` is probably used in a loop so if I assigned it to a variable I would call it *currentAccountNumber* (or 
*currAccNum*). There is often a more meaningful name to be found than *A* or *B* as in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any best practices or guidelines about the branching order of variables/identifiers consisting of many components?

That is tricky, considering naming conventions in programming languages are a mixture of tradition, readability, and ease of use: they are designed with a focus on clarity and understanding for the programmer, rather than strict linguistic consistency.
There can be a significant amount of variation between different languages, and even between different projects within the same language(!).

The general principle in most naming conventions, particularly in languages like [Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) and [C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/naming-convention-in-c/), is to make the code as readable and understandable as possible.

That is why English-like naming (despite its inconsistency) is often favored: it makes the code more intuitive to a broad audience of developers, most of whom have at least a basic understanding of English.

---

When it comes to multi-word identifiers, many coding conventions encourage programmers to use a structure that resembles natural language, because it is often more readable and intuitive. That typically involves a noun (representing the thing the variable or method deals with) followed by adjectives or verbs that provide additional context or specify actions.

For example, the [Google Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case) suggest that variable names should be short, descriptive nouns or noun phrases. Using this convention, you might name a variable `employeeNumber` or `totalWidth`.
The natural structure of English, or other spoken languages, tends to be more comfortable for most programmers because of its familiarity. It mirrors the way we naturally communicate. `customerAccountNumber` is a lot more intuitive to an English-speaking programmer than `numberAccountCustomer`, even if the latter may be more consistent in a linguistic sense.

In your examples, the natural English versions of the variable names are generally easier to understand because they follow a more familiar linguistic pattern. The consistently right-branching versions of the names, while logically consistent, are a little harder to parse because they do not match the natural word order of English.

As for the OF Language's PRIME-MODIFIER-CLASS word scheme, this does represent a more consistently right-branching approach to naming, with the more general categories (CLASS) coming first, followed by MODIFIER and then PRIME. But even in this case, the convention is designed with an eye toward making the code easier to read and understand, rather than achieving strict linguistic consistency.

---

However, your point about the inconsistencies that arise in deeply nested data structures is well taken. For complex and deeply nested structures, a more linguistically consistent naming convention might indeed aid in understanding the relationships between elements. This could be especially beneficial in contexts where the code needs to be understood by people from diverse linguistic backgrounds, or when working with particularly complex data structures.

In general, the most important factor is clarity. If a particular naming convention consistently helps you and your team understand your code more effectively, that's a strong argument in its favor.
However, if you're working in a larger development community, you may need to balance your personal preference for a consistent naming scheme against the prevailing conventions of that community.

---

And you need to consider another aspect of naming conventions: the use of **context**.

When assigning the result of a computation to a variable, the choice of name depends on the purpose of the variable in the *context* of the surrounding code. If the variable is used to store the current account number in a loop iterating over a list of customers, then `currentAccountNumber` (or `currAccNum` for brevity) is an intuitive name because it succinctly explains the purpose of the variable.

Often, there's a more meaningful name available than simply appending a letter or number to differentiate between similar variables. For example, if the two account numbers being compared belong to the sender and receiver of a transaction, you could name them `senderAccountNumber` and `receiverAccountNumber`, which provide more context than `accountNumberA` and `accountNumberB`.

Your examples (`acctNoCustomerA/acctNoCustomerB` or `customerAAcctNo/customerBAcctNo` or `noAcctACustomer/noAcctBCustomer`) highlight the challenge of coming up with a consistent naming scheme that is also intuitive and readable. While `acctNoCustomerA` is more consistent with a right-branching approach, `customerAAcctNo` might be more intuitive to many developers because it follows the English nominal structure.

In general, the best practice is to choose variable names that are clear, concise, and descriptive. Consistency is important, but not at the expense of readability or comprehension.

So while a consistently left-branching or right-branching naming scheme might be more linguistically correct, it's not necessarily the best choice for code readability, especially for developers who are used to English-like naming conventions.

---

See also "[Learning Natural Coding Conventions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4182)" from Miltiadis Allamanis, Earl T. Barr, Christian Bird, and Charles Sutton.

It references "[Part-of-speech tagging of program identifiers for improved text-based software engineering tools](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261487990_Part-of-speech_tagging_of_program_identifiers_for_improved_text-based_software_engineering_tools)" ([pdf here](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Epollock/879tainsef13/samir-postagging.pdf)), from Samir Gupta, Sana Malik, Lori Pollock and K. Vijay-Shanker.

> To aid program comprehension, programmers choose identifiers for methods, classes, fields and other program elements primarily by following naming conventions in software.
> These software “naming conventions” follow systematic patterns which can convey deep natural language clues that can be leveraged by software engineering tools. For example, they can be used to increase the accuracy of software search tools, improve the ability of program navigation tools to recommend related methods, and raise the accuracy of other program analyses.
>
> After splitting multi-word names into their component words, the next step to extracting accurate natural language information is tagging each word with its **part of speech** (**POS**) and then chunking the name into natural language phrases.
>
> State-of-the-art approaches, most of which rely on “traditional POS taggers” trained on natural language documents, do not capture the syntactic structure of program elements. In this paper, we present a POS tagger and syntactic chunker for source code names that takes into account programmers' naming conventions to understand the regular, systematic ways a program element is named.

Those articles can help to inform your research.

---

Regarding the OP's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75647431/order-of-words-in-multiple-word-variables-and-identifiers-in-general/76647995#comment135212550_76647995):

> It seems like the programming community hasn't given my specific question detailed thought

1. You are correct: the vast majority of mainstream programming conventions do not directly address the left-branching versus right-branching linguistic structure in variable or identifier naming.
   Most conventions emphasize clarity, consistency, and the use of established patterns within a specific language or ecosystem, and they usually recommend or prescribe patterns that are influenced by English syntax and readability, rather than strictly linguistic considerations.

> Assuming a logical structure of `[accounts[customers[a]].number]`, a truly perfectly right-branching name might be `Acct_CustomerA_No`, reflecting the hierarchical structure where "`Customer`" and "`A`" go together closely, but "`A`" doesn't directly connect to "`Acct`" or "`No`".

2. Your second observation introduces an interesting perspective. Using underscores or other separators to reflect different levels of hierarchy could indeed help to represent the structure of the data in the name of the variable.
   Something like `Acct_CustomerA_No` might be more intuitive and readable in some contexts, especially when dealing with complex data structures. It is a way of visually grouping related elements together, similar to how parentheses are used in mathematical expressions to show the order of operations.
   That naming scheme might take some getting used to, but it could potentially be a useful approach in certain contexts.

Comment: I have two remarks: (1) It seems like the programming community hasn't given my specific question detailed thought. (2) One observation (which I hadn't thought through when I wrote up my question): Assuming a logical structure of [accounts[customers[a]].number], a truly perfectly right-branching name might be `Acct_CustomerA_No`, reflecting the hierarchical structure where "Customer" and "A" go together closely, but "A" doesn't directly connect to "Acct" or "No".

Comment: @LoverofStructure Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comments in the answer for more visibillity.